# Why nth root of a complex number has n values and not 2n -1 values?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am studying how to find nth root of a complex number. The derivation is as follows

[image]

I think in this derivation we should consider
$$ z = r(cosθ + i sinθ) $$
$$=r(cos(θ\pm 2kπ) + isin(θ\pm 2kπ)) $$

and then for $$  k = 0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3 .....\pm n-1 $$
we should have 2n-1 values of nth root of z corresponding to different values of k.
Please help me understand what I am missing here.

Comment: The difference between $k=-1$ and $k=n-1$ is $2\pi n$.  So after dividing by $n$, the difference is $2\pi$.  So the two roots are the same number.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note
$$\begin{align}\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2(\color{blue}{-1})\pi}{n}\right)&=\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2(-1)\pi}{n}+2\pi\right)\\&=\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2(-1)\pi+2n\pi}{n}\right)\\&=\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2(\color{blue}{n-1})\pi}{n}\right)\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2(\color{blue}{-2})\pi}{n}\right)&=\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2(-2)\pi}{n}+2\pi\right)\\&=\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2(-2)\pi+2n\pi}{n}\right)\\&=\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2(\color{blue}{n-2})\pi}{n}\right)\end{align}$$
and so on so the values for $k=-1$ to $k=-(n-1)$ are just repetitions of the values $k=n-1$ to $k=1$ (in that order).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. :)